# Summarize totals given multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

So I have two tables, players and matches with structures like so:

```
                     Table "public.players"
 Column |  Type   |                      Modifiers                       
--------+---------+------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('players_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | text    | 
 wins   | integer | default 0
 loses  | integer | default 0
 rating | integer | default 1500
```

and

```
                         Table "public.matches"
    Column     |  Type   |                      Modifiers                       
---------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer | not null default nextval('matches_id_seq'::regclass)
 player1       | integer | 
 player1rating | integer | 
 player2       | integer | 
 player2rating | integer | 
 winner        | boolean |
```

Where winner is true if player1 won that match or false if player2 won that match.

Doing simple win/loss comparisons is easy using the players table, however I'm watching to do a comparison where two players have faced each other, what their records against each other are.

So I'm confused on how I'd summarize where conditions given that a given player may be listed as either player1 or player2:
P1 Wins:

```
(player1 = <player1> AND winner = true) OR (player2 = <player1> AND winner = false)
```

P2 Wins:

```
(player1 = <player2> AND winner = true) OR (player2 = <player2> AND winner = false)
```

Losses would just be the opposite of the other players wins.

Something that returned information like:

```
  id  |   name   | wins | loses | rating | wins_v_opp | loses_v_opp
------+----------+------+-------+--------+------------+------------
 4200 | Sinku    |    5 |    48 |   1191 |          1 |          4
 4201 | Kenshiro |   33 |    29 |   1620 |          4 |          1
```

What I came up with before update2 below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION matchup(text, text) AS $$
DECLARE
    player1_name ALIAS FOR $1;
    player2_name ALIAS FOR $2;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT id FROM player WHERE name LIKE $1'
        INTO player1_id
        USING player1_name;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Player1 % not found', player1_name;
    END IF;
    EXECUTE 'SELECT id FROM player WHERE name LIKE $1'
        INTO player2_id
        USING player2_name;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Player2 % not found', player2_name;
    END IF;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'WITH cte_winners AS (
            SELECT
                CASE WHEN winner THEN m.player1 ELSE m.player2 END AS player,
                COUNT(*) AS wins_v_opp,
                sum(count(*)) over() - COUNT(*) AS loses_v_opp
            FROM matches AS m
            WHERE player1 IN ($1,$2) AND player2 IN ($1,$2)
            GROUP BY player
        )
        SELECT * FROM players AS p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_winners AS cw ON cw.player = p.id WHERE p.id IN ($1,$2)'
    USING player1_id,player2_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to select matches won by `<player1>` or `<player2>`, you can use this query:

```
with cte_winners as (
    select
        id, case when winner then player1 else player2 end as player
    from public.matches
)
select *
from cte_winners
where player in (<player1>, <player2>)
```

**update**

to get desired output your can use something like this:

```
with cte_winners as (
    select
        case when winner then m.player1 else m.player2 end as player,
        count(*) as wins_v_opp,
        sum(count(*)) over() - count(*) as loses_v_opp
    from matches as m
    where player1 in (4200, 4201) and player2 in (4200, 4201)
    group by player
)
select *
from players as p
    left outer join cte_winners as cw on cw.player = p.id
where p.id in (4200, 4201)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/820e0/18)</kbd>**

**update2**

```
with cte_player as (
    select p.id, p.name, p.wins, p.losses, p.rating
    from players as p
    where p.name in ('Sinku', 'Kenshiro')
), cte_winner as (
    select
        case when winner then m.player1 else m.player2 end as player,
        count(*) as wins_v_opp,
        sum(count(*)) over() - count(*) as loses_v_opp
    from matches as m
    where
        m.player1 in (select p.id from cte_player as p) and
        m.player2 in (select p.id from cte_player as p)
    group by player
)
select
    p.id, p.name, p.wins, p.losses, p.rating,
    m.wins_v_opp, m.loses_v_opp
from cte_player as p
    left outer join cte_winner as m on m.player = p.id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/820e0/21)</kbd>**

Comment: @OverlordQ your comment is not finished :)

Comment: Now the $10,000 question is, what if I dont know the player IDs ahead of time and I wanted to select by name, wouldn't I need to join on players in the CTE?

Comment: don't know about $10,000, but I've updated the answer, take a look

Comment: Havent tested but looks good, I updated the OP with the procedure I was going to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name, wins, losses, rating
      ,count(CASE WHEN winner THEN m.player1 = p.id ELSE m.player2 = p.id END
             OR NULL) AS wins_v_opp
      ,count(CASE WHEN winner THEN m.player2 = p.id ELSE m.player1 = p.id END
             OR NULL) AS loses_v_opp
FROM  (
   SELECT  *, COALESCE(lag(p.id) OVER(), lead(p.id) OVER()) AS id2
   FROM    players p
   WHERE   p.name in ('Sinku', 'Kenshiro')
   ) p
JOIN matches m ON m.player1 IN (id, id2)
              AND m.player2 IN (id, id2)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

-> [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/72776/1)

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be a LEFT so I'll still return their W/L/rating records even if they haven't been matched up yet? Changed the schema up a bit and ended up with [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f92bb/1/0)

Comment: @OverlordQ: That's correct. Add `LEFT` to the `JOIN` if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
from public.matches
where player1 in ('<player1's number>','<player2's number>')
and player2 in ('<player1's number>','<player2's number>')
```

should return all the matches they played against each other and

```
select id
from public.matches
where (player1 = '<player1's number>' or player2 = '<player1's number>')
and (player1 = '<player2's number>' or player2 = '<player2's number>')
and winner = <condition that shows player1's wins>
```

returns the matches which a hypothetical player1 won against a hypothetical player2.

Thus getting a rating looks something like

```
select ((
    select count(distinct id)
    from public.matches
    where (player1 = '<player1's number>' or player2 = '<player1's number>')
    and (player1 = '<player2's number>' or player2 = '<player2's number>')
    and winner = <condition that shows player1's wins>
) / (
    select id
    from public.matches
    where player1 in ('<player1's number>','<player2's number>')
    and player2 in ('<player1's number>','<player2's number>')
) * 100) as percent_of_player1_wins
from dual
```

Do note that I used PLSQL syntax.

Comment: I already have ratings calculated, I'm wanting to see if there's a single query that can return me the data I have stored (wins, loses, rating) and with two additional columns detailing just the matchups between the two given players.